# Plotting non-numeric x-axis away from the y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using `matplotlib` to graph a curve with a non-numeric x-axis. I would like there to be some space between the y-axis and the start of the plot.

This code implements a subplot with a gap (on the left) & a subplot with a gap using the set_xlim method (on the right). Why do my xticklabels no longer match the the markers in the subplot on the right?

Is there a better way to shift my plot away from the axis than using `set_xlim`?

Note: The reason that I am using FigureCanvasAgg is because it is easy to stream this as a web request.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import math

def render_subplot(fig, parameters, xlim, ylim):
    ax=fig.add_subplot(parameters)

    labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
    x_range = range(10)
    if xlim: ax.set_xlim(xlim)
    if ylim: ax.set_ylim(ylim)
    ax.plot(
        x_range, [math.sin(x/3.0) for x in x_range], 'g^-',
        x_range, [math.cos(x/3.0) for x in x_range], 'b^-',
    )
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=45)

fig=Figure(figsize=(8,4))
fig.set_facecolor('white')
render_subplot(fig, 121, xlim=None, ylim=[-1.2, 1.2])
render_subplot(fig, 122, xlim=[-0.5, 12], ylim=[-1.2, 1.2])

fig.autofmt_xdate()
canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
canvas.print_png(file('gap_at_axis_examples.png', 'wb'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the `xticks` on the integer values which I think you want, you can set `xticks` just before you set the `xticklabels`

You can use your `x_range` to do this:

```
ax.set_xticks(x_range)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might find it useful to add/replace this line(s) to your code:

```
offset = 0.5
if xlim: ax.set_xlim(xlim[0]-offset, xlim[1]+offset)
```

instead of:

```
if xlim: ax.set_xlim(xlim)
```

This will put an additional offset between the y-axis and xticks.

Comment: Thanks. It will be useful to do that, but the problem wasn't the lack of the offset, but that the markers did not align with the ticks.